# unable to get source and destination geopoints into different variables

Tags: android, maps, android-mapview

Am trying to get source and destination in two different variables with respect to the user interactions on the map. Using single marker for both source and destination. In the `onTouchEvent` method am unable to differentiate the source and destination.

With those points I want to calculate the distance and draw the route on the map dynamically with user interactions.

This is my code

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView mapView) {
        final int action=event.getAction();
        final int x=(int)event.getX();
        final int y=(int)event.getY();
        boolean result=false;

        if (action==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            for (OverlayItem item : items) {
                Point p=new Point(0,0);

                map.getProjection().toPixels(item.getPoint(), p);

                if (hitTest(item, marker, x-p.x, y-p.y)) {
                    result=true;
                    inDrag=item;

                    items.remove(inDrag);
                    populate();

                    xDragTouchOffset=0;
                    yDragTouchOffset=0;

                    setDragImagePosition(p.x, p.y);
                    dragImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    xDragTouchOffset=x-p.x;
                    yDragTouchOffset=y-p.y;

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (action==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE && inDrag!=null) {
            setDragImagePosition(x, y);
            result=true;
        }
        else if (action==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && inDrag!=null) {
            dragImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            GeoPoint pt=map.getProjection().fromPixels(x-xDragTouchOffset,
                    y-yDragTouchOffset);

            slatlng[0] = pt.getLatitudeE6()/1E6;
            slatlng[1] = pt.getLongitudeE6()/1E6; 

            urlString = getUrl(slatlng[0], slatlng[1], dlatlng[0],dlatlng[1]);

            try {
                distance = getDistance(urlString);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }           
            System.out.println("Distance : "+distance);
            System.out.println("Lat : " +slatlng[0]+"Lng :"+slatlng[1]);
            OverlayItem toDrop=new OverlayItem(pt, inDrag.getTitle(),
                    inDrag.getSnippet());

            items.add(toDrop);
            populate();

            inDrag=null;
            result=true;
        }

        return(result || super.onTouchEvent(event, mapView));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Location class to solve your issue.

```
    Location locationA = new Location("point A");  

locationA.setLatitude(pointA.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6);  
locationA.setLongitude(pointB.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6);  

Location locationB = new Location("point B");  

locationB.setLatitude(pointB.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6);  
locationB.setLongitude(pointB.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6);  

double distance = locationA.distanceTo(locationB);
```

Check the Location class methods at [Location](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html)

Comment: Is there any solutions for this one??